# Combine Separate Date and Time Cells to Get the Difference in hh:mm Format (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, date-difference

I have four cells, two are dates, and two are times. I need to get a difference of these two date+time pairs in "hh:mm" format.

For instance, Cell D1 = 11/09/2018, E1= 11/10/2018, F1 = 7:00 PM, G1 = 7:15 AM. I need to basically get the difference of 11/09/2018 7:00 PM from 11/10/2018 7:15 AM and display it as "12:15". I have the following so far but I can't get the minutes to display in minutes

```
=((TEXT(D2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(F2,"hh:mm"))-(TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(E2,"hh:mm"))) * 24
```

It shows up as "12:25". is there a better way of doing this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make text before subtracting.

```
=(E2+G2)-(D2+F2)
```

Then format the output as `[hh]:mm`

[image]

Comment: The only down side with this solution is, if the total of hours go over 24, it resets it back to zero plus whatever mins/hrs after that. So 24:15 becomes 00:15.

Comment: @NuCradle if you format it `[hh]:mm` it will not.  the `[]` tells excel you ant to keep the all the hours.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after looking closely at the screenshot. It was in the text above too -- not sure why I missed it. Thanks for clarification.